# Firebase function not deleting document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Firebase function is executing successfully but the document isn't being deleted. There is no error. The ID is being passed in the correct way.

```js
exports.toremove = functions.firestore
  .document('school/toremove')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();

    const id = newValue.id;
    console.log("DELETING THE DOC with id= " + id)
    return admin.firestore().collection('notifications').doc(id).delete();
  });
```

Comment: Does the log appears in the console ? The only place you can see those kind of logs are in the Firebase console : https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/functions/logs

Answer (score -1):

use unlink() function from PHP.
reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: This is not php. This is javascript for firebase functions